# Excel Connections - Edit Links Not Working?

Tags: excel

I do not know if this has been asked elsewhere but I looked and googled around for 30 mins and couldn't seem to find much. I have an old file with some drop down boxes for certain cells in an excel spreadsheet. I never really know how it works to be honest, and there are no macros within this sheet. But somehow, there are some links between some cells within the same file.

I recently changed file names and made copies to this master file, but some of the newer copies drop down boxes no longer work, and seems to be wanting to get to the original file. I tried editing this/these link(s) under the ribbon interface using 2016 - Data > Edit Links (under connections), and it brings up a pretty dialogue box, which has this change source button. But after I clicked it and selected the correct file (it's a circular reference, so it is the current file), it simply did nothing and did not update the file name or anything else shown within the dialogue box. And of course, my links are not fixed and the drop down boxes are not working.

I have uploaded the file here with all data stripped out, but the links are still intact there for your review. Any suggestions why I am seeing this? If I want to fix the links, what can I do to achieve that without fixing each of the cells individually? Thanks!

The file is here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sn27jnQmYvqWHho6Oa0yz7PXVGU4zwPJ

Comment: I clarified my question with an edit and noted that I am trying to update the source, not to simply remove the links. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These reason you're seeing these links is that there are cells with *Data Validation* that point to an external file (cell B71, for example).

Remove all Data Validation that is referencing external files, save the file, and re-open. The links should be gone.

Comment: Is there a way I can actually update the links without going into them individually? Ultimately, I am trying to make them work again instead of removing them. There are quite a number of them around so I wasn't sure what else I can try since the tool thing doesn't seem to cooperate.

Comment: Select one of the cells with Validation pointing to an external file (B71), change the Source reference, and check "Apply these changes to all other cells with the same settings" at the bottom of the dialog box.

Comment: Hmm, right clicks doesn't seem to allow me to change source reference, and when I click into data validation, the "Apply these changes to all other cells with the same settings" is greyed out. It works for like B71, but say, B73 doesn't work apparently. And they are not all the same either... I guess I am out of luck other than to manually redo it by hand, which is fine too I guess. It's 25 30 some fields, but I thought there might be a better way...

Comment: B73 is a merged cell, once you un-merge that cell, the unmerged cells have different validation. Fixing B71 and all others with the same validation should fix the bulk of them. You can find all cells with validation by Go to (F5) -> Special -? Data Validation.